# Removing groups of duplicate elements in a list, but keeping the first in Python. Two Lists

Tags: python, list

Basically I have two lists (lengths around 4000). one has integers that represent state, the other has time values. I have groups of repeating integers in the state list that I want to remove, but keep the first, for each grouping. At the same time for any element removed in the state list I want to remove the element of the same index in the time list. I cannot use dictionaries.

(first time on this site please forgive me if i do this wrong)

This is the code I have tried so far, it cut my list in half, but I still have repeating states.

```
for i in range (len(state)):
    if state[i] == state[i-1]:
        state[i] = 0
        tt_time[i] = 0
while 0 in state:
    state.remove(0)
while 0 in tt_time:
    tt_time.remove(0)
```

Example of what I want:

```
[4,4,4,5,5,5,4,4,3,3,5,5] => [4,5,4,3,5] (for state list)
```

at the same time:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] => [1,4,7,8,11] (for time list)
```

please note both lists are the same length

Comment: please note both lists are the same length

Comment: Take a look at ```itertools.groupby```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `zip`

**Ex:**

```
state = [4,4,4,5,5,5,4,4,3,3,5,5]
time  = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

result_state = []
result_time = []
for s, t in zip(state, time):           #Iterate both lists
    if not result_state:                #Check if result lists are empty.
        result_state.append(s)          
        result_time.append(t)
    else:
        if result_state[-1] != s:       #Check if last element in result is not same as s
            result_state.append(s)
            result_time.append(t)

print(result_state)
print(result_time)
```

**Output:**

```
[4, 5, 4, 3, 5]
[1, 4, 7, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in this case:

```
from itertools import groupby


state = [4,4,4,5,5,5,4,4,3,3,5,5]
time = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

res1 = []
res2 = [time[0]]
for k, v in groupby(state):
    res1.append(k)
    res2.append(res2[-1] + len(list(v)))
res2.pop()
```

which produces:

```
# res1 -> [4, 5, 4, 3, 5]
# res2 -> [1, 4, 7, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pair adjacent items of the `state` list by zipping it with itself but with a padding of a item different from the first item, so that you can use a list comprehension to filter items that are the same as the adjacent items. Zip the list with the `tt_time` list to pair the result with items in `tt_time`:

```
states, times = map(list, zip(*((a, t) for ((a, b), t) in zip(zip(state, [state[0] + 1] + state), tt_time) if a != b)))
```

`states` becomes:

```
[4, 5, 4, 3, 5]
```

`times` becomes:

```
[1, 4, 7, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

l1 = [4,4,4,5,5,5,4,4,3,3,5,5]
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

grouped = list(map(itemgetter(0), (list(g) for _, g in groupby(zip(l1, l2), key=itemgetter(0)))))
# [(4, 1), (5, 4), (4, 7), (3, 9), (5, 11)]

print(list(map(itemgetter(0), grouped)))
# [4, 5, 4, 3, 5]

print(list(map(itemgetter(1), grouped))) 
# [1, 4, 7, 9, 11]
```